# Trying to create a hyperlinked "hashtag" when inputting text in a text box

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink, tags

I'm creating a website where users will be posting text. One of the text boxes on the "posting" page is for tags/hashtags. A user will type in this text box "#food" or "food", but as soon as they hit the space bar, I would like each of those words typed to be hyperlinked.... which after posted, will be displayed on the post as a hyperlinked tag for other users to click on.

ie. JUST like the "Tags" box here on stackoverflow as I'm posting this question.

Does anyone know how to make a text box capable for this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use inline objects for that. Instead use an editable div;

```
<div id="myInputBox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

You can also make your input-box of a block-type, but I'm not sure if all browsers will abide by those rules of inserting complex markup inside the tag then.